# How to render components using a function in a loop rather than individually

Tags: r, shiny

I have several variables each of which has a value and I display these using valueBox in an R shiny app. The variable names are fixed, but the values can vary.

Here is some dummy data to illustrate my issue:

```
variable <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
value <- c(5, 120, -1/3, 67, 2)  
df <- data.frame(variable, value)
```

Here is the shiny app code, which gives the desired output.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(

  dashboardHeader(title = "Test App"),

  dashboardSidebar(),

  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(valueBoxOutput("value_box_a")),
    fluidRow(valueBoxOutput("value_box_b")),
    fluidRow(valueBoxOutput("value_box_c")),
    fluidRow(valueBoxOutput("value_box_d")),
    fluidRow(valueBoxOutput("value_box_e"))
  )

  )

server <- function(input, output) {

  variable <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
  value <- c(5, 120, -1/3, 67, 2)

  df <- data.frame(variable, value)

  output$value_box_a <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox("a", df$value[df$variable == "a"])
    })

  output$value_box_b <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox("b", df$value[df$variable == "b"])
  })

  output$value_box_c <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox("c", df$value[df$variable == "c"])
  })

  output$value_box_d <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox("d", df$value[df$variable == "d"])
  })

  output$value_box_e <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox("e", df$value[df$variable == "e"])
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here is the desired output:
[image: desired output]

Rather than render all valueBox individually I tried to use a function in a loop. This seems to make sense given how similar they are.

Here is my attempt, which does not work:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(

  dashboardHeader(title = "Test App"),

  dashboardSidebar(),

  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(valueBoxOutput("value_box_a")),
    fluidRow(valueBoxOutput("value_box_b")),
    fluidRow(valueBoxOutput("value_box_c")),
    fluidRow(valueBoxOutput("value_box_d")),
    fluidRow(valueBoxOutput("value_box_e"))
  )

  )

server <- function(input, output) {

  variable <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
  value <- c(5, 120, -1/3, 67, 2)

  df <- data.frame(variable, value)

  for (var_name in variable) {
    output[[paste0("value_box_",var_name)]] <- renderValueBox({
      valueBox(var_name, df$value[df$variable == var_name])
    })
  }

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here is the output from my attempt:

[image: my attempt]

Can anyone suggest how to achieve what I want?

Comment: Very nice minimal working example. Good job!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one is a tricky bugger. It occurs because Shiny -- in lack of better words -- doesn't execute the code as we are used to it, but somehow stores a cache of the code.

The solution is to force Shiny to evaluate the contents of `var_name` for each loop by assigning it to a new variable:

```
  for (var_name in variable) {
    local({            ## here
      v1 <- var_name   ## here
      output[[paste0("value_box_",var_name)]] <- renderValueBox({
          valueBox(v1, df$value[df$variable == v1])
      })
    })                 ## and closing here
  }
```

You could also double down on dynamic control creation by using `insertUI`. Then you don't have to create the valueBoxOutput in the `ui`, but simply create them on the fly from `server`.